# How to get and set default values for a form from server

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a simple HTML form:

```
<div id="dialog-form-manageadvsertiser" title="Dialog title" style="display: none;">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputUserId" class="col-xs-3 control-label">Account number</label>
            <div class="col-xs-9">
                <input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field must be a number." id="User_Id" name="User_Id" value="" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputAdvName" class="col-xs-3 control-label">Advertiser name</label>
            <div class="col-xs-9">
                <input data-val="true" data-val-number="" id="AdvName" name="AdvName" value="" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to set default values for some fields, these values are dynamic, therefore I have a PHP script that returns a json representation of those values:

```
{
    "User_Id": "12345"
}
```

How can I assign this value to the form's UserID field when it loads?

I'm using jquery framework.
I would expect some kind of mechanism that triggers a POST request to the server when the for loads, and then assigns the values from the response to the form according to the field ID.

I've tried researching it on google but did not find relevant info.

Thanks!

Comment: If your `JSON` key matched the name of your form `inputs` you can use loop to do that, otherwise you have to do it manually. share your form code and json

Comment: Show ur code or json response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to make ajax call and populate the fields with default value, you will need `$.getJSON` to make the call

```
//Function for get the data and assign default value
function getValues() {
    //get json from server
        $.getJSON( "ajax/test.json", function( data ) {
            $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
              //Am assuming your input name matches with form fields
              $( "input[name='"+ key +"']" ).val(val);
        });
    });
}

//jQuery document ready
$(function(){
    //on page load 
    getValues();

    //This will trigger on change of User_id
    $("#User_Id").on('change', getValues);
});
```

and in PHP, make sure you are returning a valid json with headers

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($data_array);
```

**[Here is a working Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/dvKjyJ5iXBr0D9jrR2ov?p=preview)**

for more info on `$.getJSON` [see docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/)